# Getting the URL path to the directory of a file (PHP)

Tags: php, apache

Hi
I have a php file at, say, localhost/foo/foo/bar.php
which includes a file at localhost/foo/included.php
I need to be able to get "localhost/foo/" as a string inside included.php
If, instead of localhost/foo/foo/bar.php, it's localhost/big/burpy/lolz/here.php (still including included.php) I still need to get "localhost/foo/"
So, I need the path of the *included file* and not the one that the client requested.

I know when I see the solution I'm going to feel like a doofus, but it just escapes me at the moment. Help please? thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

```
$realpath    = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__));
$whatIwanted = substr_replace(str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $realpath), "", -6);
```

There we go :) Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: This was useful, thank you :). It is a bit localised with the substr_replace(... -6) though. What does this remove in your context? When I excluded the substr_replace(), your solution gave me exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

This how it got working for me :)

```
<?php 
    $path = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
    $path .=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]. dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);        
    echo $path;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your included file:

```
$yourdir = dirname(__FILE__);
```

or if you're using PHP 5.3.x:

```
$yourdir = __DIR__;
```

Get the document root from

```
// contains the document root, e.g. C:\xampp\htdocs
$docRoot = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
// strip drive letter if found
if(strpos($docRoot, ':') === 1) $docRoot = substr($docRoot, 2);

// directory of included file, e.g. C:\xampp\htdocs\include
$dirInclude = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
// strip drive letter if found
if(strpos($dirInclude, ':') === 1) $dirInclude = substr($dirInclude, 2);

// find the document root
$rootPos = strpos($dirInclude, $docRoot);
// if the path really starts with the document root
if($rootPos === 0){
    // example: \xampp\htdocs\include
    $visibleDir = substr($rootPos, $);
    // convert backslashes to slashes and strip drive letter
    $webPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $visibleDir);
    // yields: http://localhost/include
    echo 'http://localhost' . $webPath;
}
else{
   // included file was outside the webroot, nothing to do...
}
```

Comment: I'd tried that, but it gives "C:\xampp\htdocs\foo\", when what I want is the URL, as the client sees it, ie, "localhost/foo/"

Comment: Since the included file can be outside the webroot, the included file does not always have a path that the client can use to request your file. But you can always play with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, `__FILE__` and resolve it with `realpath()`.

Answer (score 1):

The steps for this are:

1. Use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the folder of the include file.
2. Get the server root using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`
3. Remove the document root from the include folder to get the relative include folder
4. Obtain the server url
5. Append the relative include folder to the server url